# Exclude a specific post in a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, exclude

I have a very simple query to display all my posts in a custom post type:

```
<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title('Duck');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'sessions',
        'post__not_in' => array($page->ID)
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

What I want to do is display all the posts except the `"Duck"` post, I'm getting it's ID by it's name - which normally isn't a problem, but the query still shows this post. I'm guessing I'm just not going about this the right way.

Can anyone help me out here, I was also thinking `exclude > $page->ID`or something like that - which is what I'd do in a regular loop...just not sure how to do it in a Custom Post Type.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `get_page_by_title`, it defaults to post type `page` so you will need to tell it to target the correct post_type.

Going by your post type `sessions`, this is what you need.

```php
get_page_by_title('Duck', OBJECT, 'sessions');
```

The second argument is the type of output, the default is OBJECT so thats what I used as well

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! My work around solution was just to re-arrange that page so that particular post is last in my CPT, then use `display: none` on `ul li:last-of-type`...which works, but later if the posts get re-arranged or someone forgets to leave that one last, then another unintended post could disappear. This is much better! Thank you for the help!!